# Is it possible to load asset bundle dependencies manually in Unity 5.0?

Tags: unity, c#, assets

Is it possible to tell Unity to not load asset bundle dependencies automatically so they can be loaded manually. If so, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The asset bundle dependencies are not processed in the "load", but when the asset bundle is created. Unity basically loads the entire asset bundle in at at a time, and then instantiates particular assets inside the asset bundle. To remove asset bundle dependencies at build time, take a look at the AssetBundle.PushAssetDependencies function. Any assets that are pushed into the dependency list will be automatically excluded by bundles built afterwards.